# Need to upgrade TYPO3 version 6.1.7 to latest version

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am working on TYPO3 version 6.1.7 and now my requirement is to upgrade it to latest version.

1. What do I have to keep in mind or consider while upgrading any version?
2. How can I upgrade to the typo3 version?

Comment: People are here to help. Having them read through non-question related stuff about needing help etc. is waisting their time (chit-chat is what the [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) calls it. It is also not appropriate to ask for links to be sent to you. We want answers **on this site**, because links sent to you help nobody else and links posted here will be invalid at some point, making the answer worthless.

Comment: There is documentation available at the vendor site. Please use this as it mentions everything.

Comment: Your question is too broad for this format: there are many things to do and  to consider when updating your Typo3. Please ask here about specific problems you encounter while updating

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/latest/Upgrade/ for further details on upgrading. It's possible to select different target versions like 7.6 or 6.2 in the documentation as well...